# Adding progress bar to theme from drawable file

Tags: java, android, progress-bar, android-drawable

I was using layout to display splash screen but is loading with delay and is having a time period when the screen is white now I implement to show the splash screen from drawable with background image, but I can't find a way to visualise a progress bar.
This is the theme, and I am including the splash screen background image. Is has a way to add item as progress bar some way. I try some ways with drawable but I didn't see it on the screen. Thank you

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
        <style name="Theme.AppName.SplashScreen" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.NoActionBar">
            <!-- Primary brand color. -->
            <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
            <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
            <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
            <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
            <item name="colorSecondary">@color/red</item>
            <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/red</item>
            <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
            <!-- Status bar color. -->
            <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
            <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/screen</item>
    
        </style>
    
    </resources>
```

ProgressBar Drawable.

```
<rotate
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromDegrees="270"
    android:toDegrees="270">

    <!--styling the progress bar-->
    <shape
        android:innerRadiusRatio="2.5"
        android:shape="ring"
        android:thickness="8dp"
        android:useLevel="true">
        <gradient
            android:angle="0"
            android:endColor="@color/red"
            android:startColor="#000000"
            android:type="sweep"
            android:useLevel="false" />
    </shape>

</rotate>
```